# Cannot find /libraries for installing ckeditor module

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I'm trying to install the [CKEditor Codesnippet](https://www.drupal.org/project/codesnippet) module. I've downloaded the source but I don't know how to install it.

In the module page istructions are:

> Download the plugin from http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet at least version 4.5.11.
>
> Place the plugin in the root libraries folder (/libraries).
>
> Enable CodeSnippet in the Drupal admin.
>
> Configure your WYSIWYG toolbar to include the button.

I cannot find the /libraries folder. Should I create it in the root folder of Drupal installation or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the the [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module installed/enabled. Some details about it (from its project page):

> The common denominator for all Drupal modules/profiles/themes that integrate with external libraries.
>
> This module introduces a common repository for libraries in `sites/all/libraries` resp. `sites/<domain>/libraries` for contributed modules.

Comment: I would not recommend installing libraries because it is not in a stable state, and the approach to external libraries using the libraries module is up in the air - see https://www.drupal.org/node/1704734

Answer (score 1):

You can (need to) create it in the web root.

Comment: I've just created `libraries` in root and copied codesnippet folder, but when I go to `Home  Administration  Configuration  Content authoring  Text formats and editors` I cannot find the codesnippet button to add... what else I'm missing?

Comment: Please update question with screenshot or any browser errors.

Comment: @Jepessen I am not sure, but you may need to install the [libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module, if you haven't done so.

Comment: How did installing the Libraries module solve it? I haven't written any integration for it.